# Javascript - 'toLowerCase()' not working on object property

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pull an object's property and make that string a lowercase string.  For some reason it's not working:

I have an object, `story`, that has a property called `status`.  The status reads as "Vacant" or "Occupied" or some other things.  I want to write the code so the admins of this sheet can write either "Vacant" or "vacant" and not have to worry about capitalizing.  The status also shows on the page, so it's best to show the proper capitalization of "Vacant".  But that's besides the point.

I have an if statement:

```
$.each(story, function(i){
    if(story[i].status == "vacant"){
        showVacant(i-1);    
    } else if(story[i].status == "occupied"){
        showOccupied(i-1);
    } else if(story[i].status == "feature"){
        showFeatured(i-1);
    } else {
        showVacant(i-1);
    }
});
```

I tried using the `toLowerCase();` in the if statement:

```
if(story[i].status.toLowerCase() == "vacant"){
```

but console returned the error `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`.  I also tried making it a variable with `.toString()` first as well:

```
myStatus = story[i].status.toString();
if(myStatus.toLowerCase() == "vacant"){
```

But this gives me a console error `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`

How can I make sure the strings are always lowercase when it comes to this statement?

Comment: Your status is undefined and undefined has no toString or toLowerCase methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` means that `story[i].status` is not defined, so it is not a `string`, so that the `toLowerCase()` function is not available to it.

you need to check if 'story[i].status' is set before using it:

```
if (typpeof story[i].status != "undefined"){
    //do stuff with story[i].status
}
```

Comment: This is the solution that got me to my answer.  I've simplified the if statement to just say `if(story[i].status){.../*do the statements*/}`.  The problem was that the very first object did not have a status for some reason.  It's good to catch it anyways instead of just fixing that one little problem.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined` means that `story[i].status` does not exist.

Do this instead:

```
if( "status" in story[i] ) {
    switch( story[i].status.toLowerCase() ) {
        case "vacant":
            break;
        case "occupied":
            // etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Status isn't being set properly, and instead of being "vacant" or "occupied" is returning undefined. Because of this, you cannot lowercase or toString this undefined object.

I would recommend printing out the object's properties at various spots in the code to nail down where it's not properly setting or carrying over this property.